# android getRuntime().exec() with cat command

Tags: java, android, exec, io-redirection, cat

I am using the process class to run this command

```
/sdcard/file1.mpg /sdcar/file2.mpg > /sdcard/out.mpg
```

Here is how I am trying to do it:

```
Process processx = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[] {"cat","/sdcard/file1.mpg /sdcard/file2.mpg > /sdcard/out.mpg" });

BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(processx.getInputStream()));

String line = null;
while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
      System.out.println(line);
}

// Waits for the command to finish.
processx.waitFor();
```

The command works from terminal but not when I try the above, can anyone see why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Redirection (`>`) is not the OS feature. This is a feature of shell. To make it working from java you have to run something like the following:

`/bin/sh yourcommand > yourfile`

i.e. in your case:

`/bin/sh cat /sdcard/file1.mpg /sdcard/file2.mpg > /sdcard/out.mpg`

BUT could you please explain me why are you doeing this? Do you understand that this command is exact equivalent of `cp /sdcard/file1.mpg /sdcard/file2.mpg /sdcard/out.mpg` that can be coded in pure java without running any command line? Unless you have special reasons go on it! Write pure java code when it is possible. It is easier to debug, support and maintain.

Comment: Agreed about not resorting to lauching an executable to do what can be done in java, but there is no 'cp' binary on stock android - so when someone has a decent reason to do something with an executable (from the adb shell, or when launching a root helper process on a hacked device), they use cat with a redirect.

Comment: OK AlexR, I will try a pure java approach to concatenating the files, it was because I had been working with the process class to execute some binaries in /data/data/myapp and naturally /blindly I went on to cat the files like this also

Comment: There is no cp in android shell, you need to do it with cat for sure. that's why.

Answer (score 2):

There's absolutely no reason to use 'cat' to do this.  It's not a supported or encouraged mechanism on Android, and there's no reason to launch a new executable to do what you can easily do in java code, by reading in one file and writing it out to the other.

For the record, you are trying to do a shell redirection, and that will not work since you are not executing a shell.

Comment: hadnt thought about that, the reaon i did it this way was because I am executing several commands (binaires I unpack to /data/data/myapp. I shal try a pure java approach to this particlar command

Answer (score 0):

im using this small code to execute "cat" command and most of shell commands:

```
String[] cmdline = { "sh", "-c", "cat /sdcard/file1 >> /sdcard/file2" }; 
try {
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmdline);
} catch (Exception s) {
finishAffinity();
}
```